# String concatenation in SQL doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, exec, openrowset

I am wondering why the following doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO @Data2 (FileName,Field) 
SELECT @FileName as FileName, * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK  '\\serverpath\' + @FileName  , SINGLE_CLOB) AS Contents
```

I tried also the second approach but with this one I get the error message that the variable isn't declared:

```
declare @path nvarchar(255) = 'SELECT @FileName as FileName, * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''\\serverpath\' + @FileName + ''', SINGLE_CLOB) AS Contents'

INSERT INTO @Data2 (FileName,Field)
EXEC(@path)
```

Can somebody help?
Thanks

Comment: Explain what "doesn't work" means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not pass `@FileName as FileName` using `exec`, but you can using `sp_executesql` -- but you still can not pass `@FileName` as part of `openrowset()`:

```
declare @path nvarchar(4000) = N'
  select @FileName as FileName, * 
  from openrowset(bulk ''\\serverpath\' + @FileName + '''
    , single_clob) as Contents'

insert into @Data2 (FileName,Field)
exec sp_executesql, N'@FileName nvarchar(1024))',@FileName
```

Or directly concatenating it like you are for the `bulk` source:

```
declare @path nvarchar(4000) = N'
  select '+quotename(@FileName,'''')+' as FileName, * 
  from openrowset(bulk '+quotename('\\serverpath\'+@FileName,'''')+'
    , single_clob) as Contents'

insert into @Data2 (FileName,Field)
exec sp_executesql @path
```

reference:

- [The curse and blessings of dynamic SQL - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)
- [**`sp_executesql`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `OPENROWSET` with a variable path. Check this:

--This works

```
DECLARE @Data2 TABLE(Field VARBINARY(MAX));
INSERT INTO @Data2 (Field) 
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK  'F:\Privat\StackOverflow\test.xml'  , SINGLE_BLOB) AS Contents;
SELECT CAST(Field AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) FROM @Data2;
```

--This breaks at syntax check

```
DECLARE @FileName AS VARCHAR(1000)='F:\Privat\StackOverflow\test.xml';
INSERT INTO @Data2 (Field) 
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK  @FileName  , SINGLE_BLOB) AS Contents;
SELECT CAST(Field AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) FROM @Data2;
```

--This works, but needs a physically created table. Your table variable is out of scope within the `EXEC`-execution

```
CREATE TABLE Data2(Field VARBINARY(MAX));
DECLARE @FileName AS VARCHAR(1000)='F:\Privat\StackOverflow\test.xml';
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)='INSERT INTO Data2(Field) SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' +  @FileName + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS Contents;'
EXEC(@cmd);
SELECT * FROM Data2;
GO
DROP TABLE Data2;
```

Instead of the physically created table you might use an output parameter.